# Illustrator Group selection gives different results when clicking on body vs edge of object

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm learning Adobe Illustrator and have been following this video: [Badge Drawing](https://youtu.be/Rd0vPTEheq4) from 3:20 in the video she mentions hold "Shift" and click on the edge of the object with the "Group Selection" tool and then press delete. When she does that it deletes everything else (not sure why - side question: what does "Shift" click do here?).

Once deleted she gets a **whole** object.

When I click slightly different to her or follow her exactly I can see two results.

When following her I get the same **whole** object, but if I click instead on the white body of that stroke (just under the edge or around the edge) and then press delete I get the same white body but instead of it being a **whole** object I get a **doughnut** shape where I have a hole in the middle. My question is why does it matter where I click, what difference is the edge giving compared to the body click?

Click on Edge:

[image: Click on the edge]

When clicking on body

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest I can tell, she's clicking on the **path** to ensure only that object is deselected.

The <kbd>Shift</kbd> toggles the selection/deselection of objects. By holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> she is telling AI to *deselect* the selected object she clicks.

Her entire *point* of clicking the **path** rather than the fill is to keep all other selected objects selected. So when she hits <kbd>delete</kbd> all the other objects are removed.

As to why you get a whole object versus one with a counter, no idea. That may be due to earlier construction steps in the tutorial.

---

It is cumbersome to try and scrub a video to find some specific point which is being referred to. Yes, it's easier *for you* to merely link to a video. However, actually describing steps is more conducive to better answers. I *really* don't want to sit through 10 minutes of some tutorial just to try and find some specific area. To that end, I have no idea what she was doing before or after that minute section of her tutorial.

Comment: Instruction
1.Create a normal rectangle and put a stroke on it
2.Colour the fill and stroke differently
3. Select the whole rectangle
4. go to Object -> Expand
5. Now go to "Group Selection" Tool in the menu items
6. Whilst holding "Shift" click the stroke object
7. Press "Del" and it will leave the stroke but with a transparent hole where the fill was

Now do the same against up to step 5
Here we go to a new Step 6
6. Whilst holding "Shift" click the stroke path
7. Press "Del" and it will leave you with the stroke but fully filled out in the stroke colour.

Why does that happen?

Comment: When you have a closed shape with only a stroke (circle, rectangle, etc) and you expand the stroke you create a *compound shape*. That's a shape with a "hole" in it. By clicking **only** the outer path, you remove the outer distinction of the compound shape and are left with only the inner distinction. More Info : https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95662/why-i-should-use-a-compound-shape-in-illustrator and https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html and https://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2756475&seqNum=3

Comment: What's she's doing is expanding to a compound shape, then removing part of that compound shape. She could just as easily expand, then choose `Object > Compound Shape > Release` Which would result in 2 standard (non-compound) shapes. Compounds shapes are a collection of shapes with are told to specifically interact with each other in a specific way.

Comment: I presume you meant to say Object > Compound Path > Release, difference being it's not shape but path. Otherwise Brilliant, that helps. Thanks.